# ROR: rake aborted! stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I alread tried the answers posted on this website regarding this issue. But nothing worked

I have the following setup:

rvm 1.6.32 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

Rails 3.0.7

ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

On running:

```
$rake db:migrate --trace
```

I get the following error

## Error with trace

```
(in /home/cjr/Videos/ece_project2/ece_app)

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/cjr in PATH, mode 040777

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS

WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists

WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:404: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:452: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:960: warning: already initialized constant RUBY_EXT

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:964: warning: already initialized constant RUBY

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1033: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1242: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1245: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1249: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1253: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1259: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1569: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1575: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1612: warning: already initialized constant FileList

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1638: warning: already initialized constant EARLY

/home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1968: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES

 rake aborted!

 stack level too deep

 /home/cjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383
```

Comment: Try to run `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Comment: didnt work. I got this error instead:
    rake aborted!
    
    undefined method `generate_best_match=' for 

    ActionDispatch::Routing:Module

Comment: what does rake db:migrate --trace say?

Comment: Did you add any new gems lately (such as `rake`) or update Ruby to a later version?  This could be due to conflicts with other gems as well.  Try running this command on a new app without anything except the essential gems necessary to run Rails.

Comment: i get the same error with a new app .. Is there any way to uninstall all the gems at once and then just install the required ones?

Comment: @RyanWilcox: I added the message with --trace, any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, just switch to a new RVM gemset.  For instance, `rvm --create use 1.9.2@mynewgemset` assuming you've done `rvm install 1.9.2`.  More info here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:install_ruby .. Then your gems will be empty and you can install only the ones you need to see if you can get rid of the error.

Comment: i did $ rvm implode and then did a fresh install. Everything works fine now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'bundle exec rake db:migrate' was working for me in a similar situation, but it didn't seem "right".

I found 'rvm implode' to be the cleanest method for myself (though likely overkill). My problems arose sometime after upgrading to OS X Lion, when some gems no longer appeared to be installed.

rvm implode. reinstall rvm. install ruby. install rails. bundle install.

rake db:migrate worked again without prefacing it with bundle exec.

---

side note: I'd be curious to know more about what actually is going on here. I presume its a conflict with different versions of the same gem being installed? But I couldn't find any detailed logging that pointed towards a specific direction.